# How to make a simple Multi Core multithreaded baremetal program?

Tags: c, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, posix, riscv

I'm working on a multi-core plateform, based on [Rocket-Chip](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip), it uses RISC-V ISA based cores.

My objective is to create a lightweight OS, that has a basic scheduler that can let me run multiple threads.

I tried FreeRTOS, ZephyrOS but those are not supporing multi-cores. So I decided to make a baremetal app, running in machine-mode, with just the very basic API (pthread_create, join ..).

The problem is that I'm not familiar with POSIX implementation details, nor with OS architectures. I already spent a month trying to understand what's going on in Rocket-Chip, and how baremetals work, but I'm still very far from my objective.
Can you please tell me where to begin from?
Any advice is welcome.

Best regards.

Comment: this sounds like an amazing project. Take a look at the osdev wiki as a good starting point. I highly recommend it. This page should bring you forward: https://wiki.osdev.org/Multiprocessor_Scheduling (Note: you should know that what you are trying to do is *extremely* difficult. be prepared to be frustrated, but never give up) :)

Comment: Thanks @AndreasGrapentin I see your point. In fact I don't want a real performant scheduler .. just the minimum (pthread_create + join .. i.e. basic things). All I want is to understand how I can make a scheduler that is able to run 2-3 tasks in the same processor, or for example pin each task on a separate processor. I guess The first case is feasable using interruptions + context switches .. I just need a hint or an orientation to a book or something to learn how to do this in multi-processor cases. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @noureddine-as even the 'basic' things are non-trivial.  An inter-core driver, for example, is required to interrupt between cores.  I would not want to write one, and I certainly would not like to test and debug one:(

Comment: @MartinJames since I'm working on RISC-V i begun from a light-weight "OS" called proxy kernel https://github.com/riscv/riscv-pk the proxy kernel is built ontop of a bootloader BBL. It has already many things such as IPI (for inter processor interruptions), there is also HLS (hart-local storage, note a hart is a physical core) .. So I have many peaces there I can play with. In addition to some basic virtual memory related functions. I need to add multi-core support to that, what do you think about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extremely simple SMP hello world example in SiFive's Freedom E SDK https://github.com/sifive/freedom-e-sdk/blob/master/software/smp/smp.c that might serve as a good example.  Concurrent programming is difficult in general, but luckily there's an entire discipline based around operating system design.  One of the only books I've read is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Operating_Systems , I think that'd be a good place to start.